# Find element at given index after a number of rotations

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

```
Input : arr[] : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        ranges[] = { {0, 2}, {0, 3} }
        index : 1
Output : 3
Explanation : After first given rotation {0, 2}
                arr[] = {3, 1, 2, 4, 5}
              After second rotation {0, 3} 
                arr[] = {4, 3, 1, 2, 5}
```

After all rotations we have element 3 at given index 1.

**Not Able to Understand Why starting from last rotation gives right result but if we start from rotation 0 to last in loop it gives wrong result???**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-element-given-index-number-rotations/

// Java code to rotate an array
// and answer the index query

```
 import java.util.*;

    class GFG
    {
        // Function to compute the element at
        // given index
        static int findElement(int[] arr, int[][] ranges,
                                int rotations, int index)
        {
            for (int i = rotations - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                // Range[left...right]
                int left = ranges[i][0];
                int right = ranges[i][1];

                // Rotation will not have any effect
                if (left <= index && right >= index) {
                    if (index == left)
                        index = right;
                    else
                        index--;
                }
            }

            // Returning new element
            return arr[index];
        }

        // Driver
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            // No. of rotations
            int rotations = 2;

            // Ranges according to 0-based indexing
            int[][] ranges = { { 0, 2 }, { 0, 3 } };

            int index = 1;
            System.out.println(findElement(arr, ranges,
                                     rotations, index));
        }
    }
```

This will give right result but following will produce wrong result.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rotations; i++) {

                // Range[left...right]
                int left = ranges[i][0];
                int right = ranges[i][1];

                // Rotation will not have any effect
                if (left <= index && right >= index) {
                    if (index == left)
                        index = right;
                    else
                        index--;
                }
            }
```

Comment: The order of rotation does matter. You are not guaranteed to get the same answer when you process the sequence of rotations from the last. What is the problem to be solved - to process from start to end or end to start ?

Comment: btw the version with starting from the end, does not give correct output: 1,2,3,4,5 is changed into 4,1,2,3,5 and then into 2,4,1,3,5 hence element at index=1 is 4 but the program outputs 3

Comment: @SomeDude Above algorithm with rotation start from last always gives correct output for Ranges according to 0-based indexing Example :{ 0, 4 }, { 0, 9 }.I have tested it for multiple values it always return correct output.

Check : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-element-given-index-number-rotations/

Comment: Try `{1,2,3,4,5}` and rotation sequence = `{0,3},{0,2},{0,5}` - Don't run code. Just work on paper and try start to end and end to start. Try to compare the element at index 1 in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not Able to Understand Why starting from last rotation gives right
>   result but if we start from rotation 0 to last in loop it gives wrong
>   result???

Because its not supposed to give the same output. The final results depends on the **order in which you apply the rotations**.

Suppose first you apply **{0,3}**, the array would be :

```
4 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5
```

Now you apply **{0,2}**

```
2 , 4 , 1 , 3 , 5
```

Clearly the element at index 1 is **NOT 3**

Answer (score 7):

Lets us consider given 5 length array A1.
You have applied {0,2} rotation on A1. It is changed to A2.
You have applied {0,3} rotation on A2.. It is changed to A3
Now you are looking for output index 1 in A3 (which is {0,3} rotated on A2).
So Index 1 in A3 = Index 0 in A2 (as per the logic)
Now you are looking for Index 0 in A2 (which is {0,2} rotated on A1)
So Index 0 in A2 = Index 2 in A1 (as per the logic)
Hope this explanation clears why the rotations array is iterated in reverse way.